# Ubuntu crontab backup website files won't run

Tags: backup, cron

I use my linux VPS for webhosting. I want to create backups automaticly.

Currently the database backup works, they are daily created at around 3:30 local time.

But the other backups won't do anything, in the screenshot below I added a * * * * * time notation just for testing, but it doesn't create any file.

If I copy and paste exact the same command (wihtout the time) then it runs and creates a backup.

I hope anyone can help me, thanks in advance.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOFgH.png)

Comment: The % signs in the database backup commands are escaped e.g. `date +\%Y`; in your first command, they aren't. See for example [How can I execute `date` inside of a cron tab job?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29582/65304)

Comment: Thanks, that did solve my problem. I did remove them becouse it did change my file name (I guess I used the / instead of \?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steeldriver:

> The % signs in the database backup commands are escaped e.g. date +\%Y; in your first command, they aren't. See for example How can I execute date inside of a cron tab job?

Thank you very much. I typed the `/` instead of `\` in the first place, but I did remove them becouse they changed the name. This did solve my problem.